# When you have multiple coordinators in postgres-XL, do you have any floating ip which re-direct to one coordinator?

Tags: postgres-xl

In minimum requirements, to build a master slave system, I must have two coordinators, one master and one slave.
So when you build your connection string, what is the target IP?
master?
slave?
or some floating ip to manage this

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking which coordinators node your database client should connect to it is neither.   Your app would connect to a load balancer that will connect to those nodes.   See the layout here:

https://www.postgres-xl.org/overview/